# How can I properly use Heap Analytics with Nuxt.js Router?

Tags: nuxt.js, heap-analytics, nuxt-link

I am using Heap Analytics in a Nuxt.js project. When routing between pages, Heap is displaying the title of the *previous* page as opposed to the current page. I believe this is an issue with nuxt router because if I change `<nuxt-link>`'s to regular `<a>` tags Heap displays the correct (current page) title.

I have `heap.load()` setup as part of a mixin that fires in the mounted hook. I've also tried to run it in the created hook. They both send the expected data to Heap with the exception of the `<title>`.

Nuxt config:

```
head: {
  script: [{ src: '/js/tracking/heap.js' }, ...]
},

plugins: [ '~/plugins/globals.js', ... ]
```

Plugins:

```
import AnalyticsTracking from '~/mixins/analyticsTracking.js'
Vue.mixin(AnalyticsTracking)
```

Mixin:

```
methods: {
    pageEvent() {
      if (process.client) {
       // avoid the dreaded 'heap.load() is not a function' error that results 
       // when heap is loaded multiple times.
       if (this.$store.state.scriptInit.heapLoaded) return
        
       heap.load(process.env.HEAP_KEY)
       this.$store.dispatch('scriptInit/setHeapLoaded')
      }
     }
 },
```

Page:

```
mounted() {
  this.pageEvent()
},
head() {
    return {
      title: this.currentPage.fields.seoTitle,
    }
}
```

I've read through the Nuxt router docs and do not see anything obvious that is helpful to me. I've attempted to async and defer the loading of the `/js/tracking/heap.js`, but that doesn't solve the issue either. The only solution I have found so far is by not using Nuxt router, and I would hate to not get the preload/prefetch benefits that come with it.

I would appreciate any advice in helping me solve this issue. Thanks.